# How can I copy one side of a rig to the other?

Tags: rigging, armature

I need to mirror the half part of the rigging of my character, I remember it was something with the scale or rotation.. does anyone know which was the right solution step-to-step?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mirror a bone?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/how-to-mirror-a-bone)

Comment: Sorry but isnt working :/ that's not what i need, i need to select the bones (all the half part of the rig) and then just duplicate it on a mirrored way.

Comment: Keep in mind, just mirroring isn't complete, you might need to adjust the roll of the bones and you also will want to update the names since Blender will append some numeric constant to the duplicates.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to mirror a rig down the very middle, you'll need the 3d cursor reset (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) and used as your 'Pivot Point' (<kbd>.</kbd>). That'll determine the mirror center, so long as the rig itself is placed correctly in the center (0,0,0). Now Select any half of the armature (excluding the spine/middle) and duplicate it with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, next press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> + *(the axis you are working along, usually  <kbd>X</kbd>)* to mirror it over to the other side. With the selection still instact, press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Flip Names* to update the names so something like *upper-arm.L* becomes *upper-arm.R*.

After doing this, the mirrored bones might have a different roll from the other side. To fix, select the original bones (can just invert selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> if you still have the mirrored side selected), enable *X-Axis mirror* under *Armature Options* in the toolshelf and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to fix the roll.

Comment: also the Pivot point needs to be set to 3D Cursor

Answer (score 6):

I just tried to name the bones correctly on one side (ending with .L in my case) then while the pivot center was at **(0,0,0)** as recommended here I pressed <kbd>W</kbd> and choose *Symmetrize*. BEST THING EVER! It automatically makes a duplicate with the right names, not adding the .001 at the end making them more complicated and best of all the X axis mirror option works! This means I can even copy the keyframes of one bone and paste mirror at the other if the pose is symmetrical!

1. Name the bones correctly and ending with either an (.L) or (.R.
2. Set the 3D cursor to (0,0,0) and assign the pivot point to it.
3. Select the bones you want to duplicate (all ending with their Left/Right convention.
4. Press <kbd>W</kbd> and select the option *Symmetrize*.

It helps to have *X-ray* and *Names* enabled in the viewport so you see them all.

Then, having a left and light side ready, in edit mode you can activate the X-Axis mirror and it works. In *Pose mode* you can copy the bone properties (rotation and position) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use the x-mirror(makes work easier down the road). See the duplicate that NoviceInDisguise linked.

Manually, you can do this:
Set 3D-cursor to center. Then select rotation around 3D cursor.
Choose the bones you want to mirror, duplicate them(shift + d), press S for scale, then x and then press -1. Duplicate bones will mirror over z-axis.

Answer (score 3):

Here are your steps :

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on keyboard to center pivot.
2. Press <kbd>.</kbd>(Period) to select pivot as scale point
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate bones.
4. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> then the axis you are working on (For ex:-x) and -1.
5. This should do it.

Comment: 3. should be shift + D but it worked thank you

Answer (score 1):

*I just remembered, to mirror a half part of the bones/skeleton you have to take all the bones on the half (left or right) part of the mirror, then press S (Scale) and -1, then rotate it with R (Rotation) on 180°, plus pressing X, then you will have the half part like a mirror.*
*Also, the pivot should stay at median point pivot.*