# Is there any way to mirror an already rigged mesh and skeleton in Blender?

Tags: rigging, armature

While working on my project, I completely rigged only one half of a mesh without the mirror modifier applied. I obviously want the whole thing rigged - Am Ia forced to redo the whole thing to get the other side? (Is there a way to just mirror the whole thing with the rig data?)

Comment: Possible dupe of [How can I copy one side of a rig to the other?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24026/how-can-i-copy-one-side-of-a-rig-to-the-other).

Comment: No, that's not rigged yet, my model's already applied to the skeleton, as in it's a working skeletal mesh.

Comment: Do you want to mirror your mesh or your armature?

Comment: I mirrored the armature already, I just want to mirror the mesh and have it apply to the other side with the weight data of my current side.

Comment: this can be done without applying your mesh's mirror modifier. Just name your bones with .R/.L