# Mirroring the rig positions

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, mirror, rigify

I have positiones the Right hand side of my rigify Armature, and not I don't want to go through positioning my left hand side. I know there is a way to do that but I do not remember how.

[image]

**Never mind people my PC crushed and all the data is now gone, I actually can't even get in, because it says that I don't have an operating system**

Comment: See also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24026/how-can-i-copy-one-side-of-a-rig-to-the-other/24028#24028