# Copying pose to mirrored side of character results in asymmetry

Tags: rigging, armature

My character is symmetrical when in rest pose, but when I move one arm into a pose and then copy the pose to the other arm with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, it comes out somewhat different. There were a few pose libraries and actions, and I tried clearing those all out to see if it would help. It doesn't.

[image: side view of armature showing lack of symmetry]

What do I need to do to get the poses to be symmetrical?

[image]

Comment: I don't know where the problem comes from but if you deactivate the X-Axis Mirror, delete the left arm, then Symmetrize the right arm, it will fix the problem... it doesn't answer your question though   ;)

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, that does answer the question, for all intents and purposes. I had to look up how to do that, there was a good explanation in this other answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66269/7548.

Comment: actually that fixed the problem but I was enable to understand what was wrong with your armature, I tried the IK rotation, also in Edit mode bones rotation with ctrl R, but it didn't work...

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. It would be nice to know why but if the few people who have looked at this couldn't figure it out i imagine it was an artifact. I thought of redoing the arm before but didn't know about that symmetrize part.