# Disable mirrored armatures

Tags: armature, mirror

I would like to control the arms independently but I don't know how to turn off mirroring. The modifier tab shows nothing.

I am using Blender 2.8.
Here is the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1je2Z5CTc7zWl4HyceD0LypM0mvyiBnqE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/how-to-mirror-a-bone

Comment: in the file you link, the 2 arms are independent, so what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Really? It must be my settings then