# Cannot get armature to move the mesh

Tags: mesh, armature

I made the Armature Layout to mirror up to my mesh but I cannot get it to symmetrize.

The armature also will not connect to the mesh.

When I move it it doesn't grab the mesh, this is my first project, so I'm thinking its something simple that I just overlooked. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15063/44386) answer regarding mirroring bones.

The armature has to be a "parent" of the mesh in order to move it. In order to do this, in Object Mode select the mesh then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click the armature. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to parent and select With Automatic Weights for best results. You can move the bones by selecting the armature and switching to pose mode.

I suggest watching/reading a comprehensive guide for rigging a character and adjusting it, as it's challenging, even for intermediate users.